# SQL query if not null enter field value

Tags: mysql, informix

Trying to create SQL query where in reading a field if the field entry meets the condition or is null it enters the value read if not it skips the whole select for that line.

```
SELECT a.name, b.age 
CASE
    WHEN a.birthday = b.birthday THEN vlaue?
    WHEN a.birthday != b.birthday THEN skip?
    ELSE is null THEN null
END AS birthday

FROM information a, tracking b

WHERE a.name = b.name
```

So it would enter the name and age if the birth date matches or is a null but if the birth date does not match it would not enter name and age at all.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Some example data and expected output would help clarify the specification. i.e what is meant by "skips the whole select for that line"? Does that mean the row satisfying that condition should not be returned? That row should be omitted from the resultset? How many columns are supposed to be in the resultset?

Comment: Which one can be null, `a.birthday` or `b.birthday`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use where  for this

```
  SELECT a.name, b.age 
    CASE
        WHEN a.birthday = b.birthday THEN 'value'
        ELSE null
    END AS birthday

  FROM information a
  INNER JOIN  tracking b ON  a.name = b.name
  WHERE a.birthday != b.birthday
```

(and you should use explict join notation .. is more readble)

or if you need also when don't match use left join

```
 SELECT a.name, b.age 
    CASE
        WHEN a.birthday = b.birthday THEN 'value'
        ELSE null
    END AS birthday

  FROM information a
  LEFT JOIN  tracking b ON  a.name = b.name
  WHERE a.birthday != b.birthday
```

Comment: This will skip the null case as well, because `x != y` is null when either of them is null.

Comment: Thank you, the join is working for the 'skip' portion.  I miss labeled | typed above and need WHERE a.birthday = b.birthday THEN display value in a.birthday.  I tried CASE WHERE a.birthday = b.birthday THEN a.birthday with no luck

Comment: I think I got it, changed from INNER to LEFT.

Comment: @cw2   well  if you need the result also when the on clause don't match the left join is th right solution .. ( i  con't know youe exact problem) ..  answer updated ..